# Can we keep char[undetermined_during_compile_time_size] inside of boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, char, shared-ptr

I could have a `queue<char*> file_queue;` but than I would need to clean up after each `char*`. I have a dinamic variable `int buff_length;` that would be length of each char in `file_queue`. It would be set once from a `config` file before `queue` creation. So I wonder - is it possible to keep `char[buff_length]` inside one `boost::shared_ptr` and how to do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `shared_array`:

```
boost::shared_array<char> ptr(new char[buff_length]);
```

Any reason why `std::string` or `std::vector<char>` is not appropriate for your situation?

---

Note, with C++11 you can use the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> ptr(new char[buff_length]);
```

`std::unique_ptr` has a specialization to deal with arrays. I was under the mistaken belief that `boost::shared_ptr` did too, but evidently that was incorrect.

Comment: "has a partial specialization to properly deal with arrays." <-- Are you sure that's `boost::shared_ptr`? I don't believe that's the case. That's why there's `boost::shared_array`. (Note that `std::shared_ptr` does have that specialization)

Comment: Isn't [shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) the correct solution for `new []` and `delete []`

Comment: I'd add that you probably shouldn't do this since there's no way to know the size of the array unless you never change it, in which case a compile-time constant would be better. You should probably use `std::pair` or something so the array carries its length around too.

Comment: Could you point to the documentation of this fact? I couldn't find it.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it had a specialization, but I was wrong. I have corrected my answer. It's `std::unique_ptr` that has the specialization.

Comment: `test.cc:3:44: error: conversion from ‘char*’ to non-scalar type ‘boost::shared_ptr<char []>’ requested`

Comment: `Any reason why std::string is not appropriate for your situation?` A simple reason would be if the OP isn't storing text, but an array of small values which could really be anything.

Comment: @IronMensan That would be a good reason not to use it. I just thought I'd mention it in case the OP simply hadn't thought of it.

Comment: I dont want to keep catched data from binary files inside of string=)

Comment: @Kabumbus: there's really nothing wrong with doing that other than possibly confusing readers. Which I find an acceptable reason. Anyway, you can also do this with a `shared_ptr`: just use a custom deleter that calls `delete[]` (and maybe there's one in boost already).

Comment: @IronMensan: If that was the case, the question would be *Any reason why `std::vector<char>` is not appropriate for your situation?*

Answer (score 4):

Use boost::shared_array<..>, see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) for the documenation.